# Issue with Collection backup and restore

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I have a Solr Cloud with 2 node cluster. It has 2 replicas one on each node with a single shard.

The cores created are {collection_name}_shard1_replica1 and  {collection_name}_shard1_replica2.

When I perform a collection backup, and restore into a new collection, the documents are indexed properly on both the nodes, However the cores created are named differently {collection_name}_shard1_replica0 and  {collection_name}_shard1_replica1

Additionally, when I delete or add documents it gets only deleted from one node which means the replication does not work. I also noticed on one node I do not have the index folder on one of the nodes from where document is not getting deleted or added.

What could I be possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So all those interested in the solution, a restart of all the nodes sequentially helped (still not able to digest why it was required and is missing in the documentation).